# I am developing a React app on the local network. How can I upload files to a common folder accessible to anyone within the same IP network?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, local-storage, cloudinary

I'm developing an application to use at my company. So far i'm backing my images and pdf files to Cloudinary but I would like to upload and download them from a local folder accessible to anyone connected on the IP network. Is there anyone who has done this using Axios? The application is running well, but we just want to run everything locally.

Answer (score 2):

Axios makes HTTP requests. It can upload files via HTTP. It can't upload using other protocols (such as Windows File & Print Sharing).

You can write and run a web service which you can upload to using HTTP and which saves uploaded files to a directory on the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you app will be running locally and on same ip where you need to store your files basically you can use fs module from node js ( or writefile with the backend language that you are using ) and create file in the folder which will be accessible for everyone who has access to that ip.

Comment: Thank you so much, I willl update you once I have coompleted everything.